# Send value of checkbox to control.php file via href method

Tags: php, checkbox, parameters, href

I have a control.php file for my webcam and I'm able to send commands to it by the use of an image map's href link like this:
href="command.php?cmd=1". In the control.php is a sleep timer which stops the move of the camera after 1 second. All works well. Now I'd like to add a checkbox to the webcams streaming page and would like to send the value of the checkbox also to command.php in addition to the comnand. It would either stop the move of the cam after one second or not, dependent on the checkbox value. I tried all in php and even JS but I'm too stupid to get it done. Any help is highly appreciated! Cheers, Falk

Comment: Whats the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript event onclick() on your checkbox and an AJAX call to your second PHP script. With `this` you pass the checkbox object and its data as parameter.

```
<input type='checkbox' onclick='moveCamera(this);'>

<script>
    function moveCamera(checkbox) {
       var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
       var url = 'command.php';
       var params = 'cmd=1&checked=' + checkbox.checked;

       http.open('POST', url, true);
       http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
       http.onreadystatechange = function() {
           if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
           // Here you can put code that will be executed after the call is complete
           }
       }
       http.send(params)
    }
</script>
```

Now you can access `checked` exactly like `cmd` in your second php script.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks Christoper! Maybe I was not precise enough what I'm unable to do. This is what now works well:

```
<center><h3 class="auto-style21">Camera Control 
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()" checked="checked"> AutoStop aktiviert: <i id="demo"></i></h3>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("myCheck").checked;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
```

But now, rather than sending the auto=true or false I'd like to send the x value, please see below:

```
<map name="image-map">
<img src="ptz.jpg" usemap="#image-map">
<area alt="Up" title="Up" target="control" coords="127,31,25" shape="circ" 
href="control.php?cmd=0&auto=false">
<area alt="Down" title="Down" target="control" coords="127,170,30" shape="circ" 
href="control.php?cmd=2&auto=false">
<area alt="Left" title="Left" target="control" coords="39,93,30" shape="circ" 
href="control.php?cmd=4&auto=false">
<area alt="Right" title="Right" target="control" coords="217,93,25" shape="circ" 
href="control.php?cmd=6&auto=false">
<area alt="UpRight" title="UpRight" target="control" coords="181,49,22" 
shape="circ" href="control.php?cmd=91&auto=true">
<area alt="UpLeft" title="UpLeft" target="control" coords="71,49,22" 
shape="circ" href="control.php?cmd=90&auto=true">
<area alt="DownLeft" title="DownLeft" target="control" coords="63,144,22" 
shape="circ" href="control.php?cmd=92&auto=true">
<area alt="DownRight" title="DownRight" target="control" coords="188,144,22" 
shape="circ" href="control.php?cmd=93&auto=true">
<area alt="Stop" title="Stop" target="control" coords="126,95,46" shape="circ" 
href="control.php?cmd=1&auto=true">
</map>
</center>
```

I tried document.write, but again, I'm too stupid for the crazy syntax. 
document.getElementById --> InnerHTML works fine, this is the solution now, just in case someone is curious:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("myCheck").checked;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
var up = "<area alt=\"Up\" title=\"Up\" target=\"control\" 
coords=\"127,31,25\" shape=\"circ\" href=\"control.php?cmd=0&auto=";
var down = "<area alt=\"Down\" title=\"Down\" target=\"control\" 
coords=\"127,170,30\" shape=\"circ\" href=\"control.php?cmd=2&auto=";
var left = "<area alt=\"Left\" title=\"Left\" target=\"control\" 
coords=\"39,93,30\" shape=\"circ\" href=\"control.php?cmd=4&auto=";
var right= "<area alt=\"Right\" title=\"Right\" target=\"control\" 
coords=\"217,93,25\" shape=\"circ\" href=\"control.php?cmd=6&auto=";
var upright = "<area alt=\"UpRight\" title=\"UpRight\" target=\"control\" 
coords=\"181,49,22\" shape=\"circ\" href=\"control.php?cmd=91&auto=";
var upleft = "<area alt=\"UpLeft\" title=\"UpLeft\" target=\"control\" 
coords=\"71,49,22\" shape=\"circ\" href=\"control.php?cmd=90&auto=";
var downleft = "<area alt=\"DownLeft\" title=\"DownLeft\" target=\"control\" 
coords=\"63,144,22\" shape=\"circ\" href=\"control.php?cmd=92&auto=";
var downright= "<area alt=\"DownRight\" title=\"DownRight\" 
target=\"control\" coords=\"188,144,22\" shape=\"circ\" href=\"control.php? 
cmd=93&auto=";
var autostop = x + "\">";
document.getElementById("camup").innerHTML = up + autostop;
document.getElementById("camdown").innerHTML = down + autostop;
document.getElementById("camleft").innerHTML = left + autostop;
document.getElementById("camright").innerHTML = right + autostop;
document.getElementById("camupright").innerHTML = upright + autostop;
document.getElementById("camupleft").innerHTML = upleft + autostop;
document.getElementById("camdownleft").innerHTML = downleft + autostop;
document.getElementById("camdownright").innerHTML = downright + autostop;
}
</script>

<map name="image-map">
<img src="ptz.jpg" usemap="#image-map">
<p id="camup"></p>
<p id="camdown"></p>
<p id="camleft"></p>
<p id="camright"></p>
<p id="camupright"></p>
<p id="camupleft"></p>
<p id="camdownleft"></p>
<p id="camdownright"></p>
<!--
<area alt="Up" title="Up" target="control" coords="127,31,25" shape="circ" 
href="control.php?cmd=0&auto=false">
<area alt="Down" title="Down" target="control" coords="127,170,30" 
shape="circ" href="control.php?cmd=2&auto=false">
<area alt="Left" title="Left" target="control" coords="39,93,30" shape="circ" 
href="control.php?cmd=4&auto=false">
<area alt="Right" title="Right" target="control" coords="217,93,25" 
shape="circ" href="control.php?cmd=6&auto=false">
<area alt="UpRight" title="UpRight" target="control" coords="181,49,22" 
shape="circ" href="control.php?cmd=91&auto=true">
<area alt="UpLeft" title="UpLeft" target="control" coords="71,49,22" 
shape="circ" href="control.php?cmd=90&auto=true">
<area alt="DownLeft" title="DownLeft" target="control" coords="63,144,22" 
shape="circ" href="control.php?cmd=92&auto=true">
<area alt="DownRight" title="DownRight" target="control" coords="188,144,22" 
shape="circ" href="control.php?cmd=93&auto=true"> 
-->
<area alt="Stop" title="Stop" target="control" coords="126,95,46" 
shape="circ" href="control.php?cmd=1&auto=true">
</map>
</center>
<iframe name="control" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

Don't forget to call myFunction on body load.

Many thanks again and Cheers, Falk